# How can I start Debian EC2 instance bypassing the ugly OptInRequired prompt?

Tags: amazon-web-services, debian

I tried to start a new Debian EC2 instance using the API and I found this ugly error:

> Instance creation failed => OptInRequired: In order to use this AWS
>   Marketplace product you need to accept terms and subscribe. To do so
>   please visit
>   http://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp?sku=3f8t6t8fp5m9xx18yzwriozxi

I google a little bit and I found this https://wiki.debian.org/Amazon/EC2/FAQ page which doesn't give a lot of explanation and is missing to provide an solution that can be used in automation.